# regex sed sql database hash:salt extraction

Tags: regex, database, bash, sed, command-line

I'm looking at a raw sql database with emails, usernames, hashed passwords, salts and IP addresses. I'm trying to extract only the hashes and saltes. Here's an example:

```
user@email.com:username:b30805e05c07782d3901bf8814c8cb9d:2WPe'KKYUti3ts2E>$np,:11.22.33.44
user2@email.com:username2:969b9be2f311ac32b7f5c475b115fae6:<t%a!>[4?:OqGHvYWYdZ0:44.33.22.11
user3@email.com:username3:550854338c55ef110fdc599806f087e6:;yzkeZ/FgCMqM:8&Z!S0r:12.34.56.78
user4@email.com:username4:a5477d971ff85fd4052cd745677e6751:&PmDLnlh{fW[&KULDpYz@:87.65.43.21
```

I thought about separating each section at the colon (`:`) and removing everything on the right of the last colon occurence but there's a colon is half the salts. So the number of colon's in a line isn't consistent. I'm totally stumped. Someone please help.

Comment: So you know you salt is between the last `:` and the second `:`, your hash is between the first `:` and the second `:` - based on this you can apply lookaheads and lookbehinds to construct a regexp that will fetch it. Many tools like regexpal.com will come handy if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^([^:]*:){2}([^:]*):(.*):.*$/\2 \3/' file
```

You know that the first three fields and the fifth respect the field separator but that the fourth does not. Remove the first two fields, keep the third and use greed to identify the fourth i.e. `(.*):` will return the largest string that ends in `:`.

Answer (score 0):

The below regex should help you:

```
^(?:.*?):(?:.*?):(.*?):(.*):.*$
```

or

```
^(?:(?:.*?):){2}(.*?):(.*):.*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/03wuCu/1

Test:

```
user@email.com:username:b30805e05c07782d3901bf8814c8cb9d:2WPe'KKYUti3ts2E>$np,:11.22.33.44
user2@email.com:username2:969b9be2f311ac32b7f5c475b115fae6:<t%a!>[4?:OqGHvYWYdZ0:44.33.22.11
user3@email.com:username3:550854338c55ef110fdc599806f087e6:;yzkeZ/FgCMqM:8&Z!S0r:12.34.56.78
user4@email.com:username4:a5477d971ff85fd4052cd745677e6751:&PmDLnlh{fW[&KULDpYz@:87.65.43.21
```

Output:

```
Match 1
Group 1.    24-56   `b30805e05c07782d3901bf8814c8cb9d`
Group 2.    57-78   `2WPe'KKYUti3ts2E>$np,`

Match 2
Group 1.    117-149 `969b9be2f311ac32b7f5c475b115fae6`
Group 2.    150-171 `<t%a!>[4?:OqGHvYWYdZ0`

Match 3
Group 1.    210-242 `550854338c55ef110fdc599806f087e6`
Group 2.    243-264 `;yzkeZ/FgCMqM:8&Z!S0r`

Match 4
Group 1.    303-335 `a5477d971ff85fd4052cd745677e6751`
Group 2.    336-357 `&PmDLnlh{fW[&KULDpYz@`
```

Answer (score 0):

I upvited the `sed` of @potong, that is only one command.
More complex are `awk` and `cut`:

```
awk -F: '{printf("%s %s", $3, $4); for (i=5;i<NF;i++) printf(":%s",$i); print ""}' file
cut -d: -f3- <(rev file|cut -d: -f2- |rev)
```